# MySQL 3 table join with count from one table and max timestamp from another

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables with sample data like below.  I'm trying to get a report of the agent names, the number of clients for the agent, and the last time the agent signed in.  If the agent has no client he won't have any record (but could have a last login date).  Conversely it's possible for an agent to have clients, but have never signed in.

```
table agents
|    id  |   first   |   last    |
----------------------------------------
|    1   |   dave    | schultz   |
|    2   |   bobby   | clarke    |
|    3   |   ed      | hospidar  | 
|    4   |   derek   | smith     |

table agentclients
|   id   |   agentid   |   clientid    |
----------------------------------------
|    1   |   2         | 345           |
|    2   |   3         | 347           |
|    3   |   3         | 221           | 
|    4   |   1         | 567           |

table loginhistory
|   id   |   userid   |   usertype    |   ts 
-------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |   2        | A    |  2018-11-17 14:16:44   |
|    2   |   3        | A    |  2018-11-24 20:46:16   |
|    3   |   4        | A    |  2018-11-27 13:07:58   |
|    4   |   1        | A    |  2019-01-05 13:45:01   |
|    5   |   4        | A    |  2019-01-19 06:36:23   |
|    6   |   3        | A    |  2019-01-24 02:13:44   |

Results:
agent id | agent name     | clients |  last login
------------------------------------------------------- 
1    | dave schultz   |    1    |  2019-01-05 13:45:01
2    | bobby clark    |    1    |  2018-11-17 14:16:44
3    | ed hospidar    |    2    |  2019-01-24 02:13:44
4    | derek smith    |    0    |  2018-11-27 13:07:58
```

I can seem to get the count, or the max login, but if I try to join all 3 the count is incorrect.

```
SELECT a.id, a.first, a.last, count(ac.clientid) as 'client count'
  FROM agents a
LEFT JOIN agentclients ac on a.id = ac.agentid
WHERE a.agentdeleted = 0
GROUP BY ac.agentid;
```

works for counting clients

If I try to add in the max() the count breaks:

```
SELECT a.id, a.first, a.last, count(ac.clientid) as 'client count',
       max(l.ts) AS 'lastlogin'
  FROM agents a
LEFT JOIN agentclients ac on a.id = ac.agentid
LEFT JOIN loginhistory l on l.userid = a.aid and l.usertype = 'A'
WHERE a.agentdeleted = 0
GROUP BY ac.agentid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the amount of unique record by an agent in `agentclients` table. You can do it with help `DISCTINCT` by `agentclients.id` column

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.first, 
       a.last, 
       COUNT( DISTINCT ac.id) as 'client count',
       max(l.ts) AS 'lastlogin'
FROM agents a
LEFT JOIN agentclients ac on a.id = ac.agentid
LEFT JOIN loginhistory l on l.userid = a.aid and l.usertype = 'A'
WHERE a.agentdeleted = 0
GROUP BY ac.agentid;
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim!  I thought that might be the answer but I guess I never actually tried it.